# CSS group every 3 rows together using same background color and adjust last or last two rows

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm able to group every 3 rows the same color, but I want the last row to group with the last group.  Is that possible using CSS?

If there's only one row left,then group it with the last group.  So the last group is a group of 4 rows.

If there's two rows left at the end, then break it up and make 2 groups of 4 at the end of the list.

http://jsfiddle.net/gnurw6ed/

```
tr:nth-child(6n), tr:nth-child(6n-1), tr:nth-child(6n-2) {
background: white;
}
tr:nth-child(6n-3), tr:nth-child(6n-4), tr:nth-child(6n-5) {
    background: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, in CSS you can't check how many rows left in your `table`.

But, you can simply do it with JS. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gnurw6ed/1) is a demo.

```js
var rowCount = $('#table tr').length;
if (rowCount % 3 == 1) {
    $('#table tr:last').css("background", "grey");  
}
else if (rowCount % 3 == 2) {
    $('#table tr:nth-last-child(5)').css("background", "white");   
    $('#table tr:nth-last-child(2)').css("background", "grey");       $('#table tr:last').css("background", "grey");  
}
```

```css
tr:nth-child(6n-3), tr:nth-child(6n-4), tr:nth-child(6n-5) {
    background: grey;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>11</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply!  I'm trying out the Meteor Leaderboard example and I was trying to figure out how to group the players together in groups of three and then adjust the last row or last two rows accordingly.  Is there an easy way to do this in Meteor js framework.

Comment: @user2411007 You can simply do it with js, are you interested in js demo?

Comment: Oh yes please!  Thank you so much.

Comment: Go thru the list and group rows in groups of 3.  Now the last row could be two or one row left over.  If it's one row left over, then group it with the last group of 3 so that the last group is a group of 4.  If there's two rows left over, then one row would group with the second to last group of 3 and the other row would group with the last group.  Now the list would contain TWO groups of 4.

Comment: you did it!  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @user2411007 glad to help you!